# Perf record em aplicação MPI

Tags: linux, profiling

Gostaria de coletar estatísticas de uma aplicação MPI

Para gravar a aplicação sendo executada em uma única máquina, eu posso usar o comando:

`perf record mpirun -np $NUMBER_OF_CORES app_name`

Porém, ao executar este comando para distribuir a tarefa em mais de uma máquina, os eventos registrados são apenas da máquina local - a qual eu disparei a execução

Para registrar cada um dos processos, criei um script que faz a chamada do perf em cada um dos sub-processos

```
#!/bin/bash
app=$1
perf record -m 512G -o "${app}-${RANDOM}.perf.data ${app}
```

E executo da seguinte maneira:

`mpirun -np $NUMBER_OF_CORES perf_record.sh app_name`

Porém, os arquivos gerados não gravaram nenhum evento

`The app_name-123.perf.data file has no samples!`

1 - O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

2 - Existe alguma outra ferramenta que seja mais indicada para usar com aplicações MPI?

Obs, eu estou realmente interessado no tempo gasto em cada uma das funções do programa e não no tempo de comunicação

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o problema estava em `-m 512G`, passando um valor alto assim, nenhum evento era gravado, [conforme descrito aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584439/what-is-the-exactly-perf-buffer-size).

Essa *flag* havia sido adicionada para contornar o problema

```
Permission error mapping pages.
Consider increasing /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb,
or try again with a smaller value of mmap_pages.
```

Mas na verdade a solução correta seria adicionar permissões de escrita para o usuário, [conforme descrito aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14256). Isso poderia ser feito através dos comandos:

De forma temporaria:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid'
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict'
```

De forma persistente:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo kernel.perf_event_paranoid=-1 >> /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf'
sudo sh -c 'echo kernel.kptr_restrict=0 >> /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf'
```